# Magento 2 : Add Import new Entity type in "Import Settings"

Tags: magento2

I am not sure how to create new entity type in Import Settings dropdown.
What would be the best way to add a custom value in dropdown ?

[image]

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ext-best-practices/tutorials/custom-import-entity.html check this

Comment: Thankyou for the comment.